# Why is the python interpreter making the socket function uncallable in TCP socket connection?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I tried to create a TCP connection with the client and server on my machine but the program will not run being that the socket() function is not callable. The same applies to the client side. Please help

[This is the sample code on the server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdzx5.png)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: Sorry but down voted for posting a link to an image that contains the code. Please edit your question so it contains the code in a text with code block format.

Comment: Here is a more detailed explanation of  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 1):

After you `import socket`, `socket` is not *the socket function*, but the *module* 'socket'; the callable class is `socket.socket`.

Comment: Appreciate it. It has helped